# fetching document from iCloud giving me 3/4 content of that document not the full content

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, document, icloud

I'm new to iPhone Development.

I have integrated iCloud storage in my application. I am successful in uploading documents on iCloud.

My document's size is around 126799 bytes. During uploading on iCloud I have made sure that a proper document is uploaded on iCloud by printing its length and content on the console. But when I am fetching document from iCloud it only gives me 3/4 of the content of that document. I have also checked this on console by printing its length and content.

```
/////====== variables are declared in interface file

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
               URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) 
    {
        NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
        // TODO: Load document... 
        [self loadDocument];
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    }
}



- (void)loadDocument{

     NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
     _query = query;
    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];


    NSString *filename = @"supplimentlistdescription.txt";
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like '%@'",filename,NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
    [query setPredicate:pred];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) 
        name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification 
        object:query];

    [query startQuery];
}


- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];
    [query disableUpdates];
    [query stopQuery];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self    
        name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
        object:query];

    _query = nil;

    [self loadData:query];
}

- (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {

    if ([query resultCount] == 1) 
    {

        NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
        self.doc = doc;
        [self.doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
            {
                if (success) 
                {                
                    NSLog(@"iCloud document opened");                    
                }
                else 
                {                
                    NSLog(@"failed opening document from iCloud");                
                }
            }
        ];
    }
    else 
    {

        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *fileurlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/Federal Rules of Civil Procedure"];
        NSLog(@"fileurlstring:%@",fileurlstring);
        ubiquityURL = [[filemgr URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]        
            URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileurlstring];
        [ubiquityURL retain];
        NSLog(@"ubiquityURL1:%@",ubiquityURL);

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:[ubiquityURL path]] == NO)
        {
            [ubiquityURL retain];

            [filemgr createDirectoryAtURL:ubiquityURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
            [ubiquityURL retain];

        }

        ubiquityURL = [ubiquityURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"supplimentlistdescription.txt"];
        [ubiquityURL retain];
        NSLog(@"ubiquityURL:%@",ubiquityURL);

        Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquityURL];  
        self.doc = doc;

        [doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] 
            forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating 
            completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
            {            
                if (success) {
                    [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
                        {                
                            NSLog(@"new document opened from iCloud");                
                        }
                    ];                
                }
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

-

```
///Note.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Note : UIDocument

@property (strong) NSString * noteContent;
@end
```

-

```
#import "Note.h"
@implementation Note
@synthesize noteContent;

- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName 
    error:(NSError **)outError
{

    if ([contents length] > 0)
    {
        self.noteContent = [[NSString alloc] 
                            initWithBytes:[contents bytes] 
                            length:[contents length] 
                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
        NSLog(@"loadFromContents1");
        NSLog(@"noteContent:%@",noteContent);
        NSLog(@"noteContent.length:%d",noteContent.length);
    }
    else
    {
        // When the note is first created, assign some default content
        self.noteContent = @"Empty"; 
    }

    return YES;
}


- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{
    if ([self.noteContent length] == 0)
    {
        //self.noteContent = @"Empty";

        NSString *FolderName = @"Federal Rules of Civil Procedure";
        NSString *fileName = @"supplimentlistdescription.txt";

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        [FolderName retain];
        NSString *fileName1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",documentsDirectory,FolderName, fileName];  
        NSLog(@"fileName1:%@",fileName1);

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileName1];
        noteContent =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"noteContent:%@",noteContent);
        NSLog(@"noteContent.length:%d",noteContent.length);
    }

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:[self.noteContent UTF8String] 
                      length:[self.noteContent length]];
}

@end
```

Can you please tell me whats can be the problem? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to show some code to get a solution.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it and let me know what is wrong in code. Thank you

Comment: The only "obvious" thing I see is right at the end, you're doing [NSData dataWithBytes:length:] with bytes from an utf8 string and the length of noteContent. An UTF-8 is not necessarily the same length in bytes as the NSString's length. Beyond that, this problem is sadly probably easier to find in a debugger than reading code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.  I am yet not getting the solution. How do i solve this problem? Length is not the concern but atleast whole text document content should visible to me and i am not getting it. Please help me  in other way.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem like your before.

You should use

for writing

```
[self.noteContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

for reading

```
self.noteContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:contents encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Example :

```
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{

    if ([contents length] > 0) {
        self.noteContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:contents encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } else {
        self.noteContent = @""; // When the note is created we assign some default content
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noteModified" 
                                                        object:self];        

    return YES;

}

// Called whenever the application (auto)saves the content of a note
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{

    if ([self.noteContent length] == 0) {
        self.noteContent = @"";
    }

    return [self.noteContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


}
```